# How to change the values within the group?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I created a column of nesting success with a value of "1"  if nest's fate was "rearing" or "fledged", and 0 if nest's fate was "nest failed". For some cases, the nest's fate was "rearing" in the first visit and "failed" for the second visit. In such cases, success of a single nest turned out to be both 1 and 0 (see nest "D063" and "D063").

How to remove "1"s or assign "NA", and only keep "0"s in the cases with both 1 and 0 in the success of the same nest?

In other words, I'd like to have only one success outcome per nest (single 1 or 0), not multiple. And, I want to keep all the rows.

[My data looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBOoC.png)

Example data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("14/06/2018", "17/05/2018", 
"21/05/2018", "5/05/2018", "6/05/2018"), class = "factor"), nest.code = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("D046", 
"D047", "D062", "D063", "W18003"), class = "factor"), year = c(2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), species = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AA", 
"BB"), class = "factor"), visit = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), eggs = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), chicks = c(0L, NA, NA, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L), fate = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("fledged", 
"incubating", "nest failed", "rearing", "unknown"), class = "factor"), 
    success = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 
    NA, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
))
```

This is the code I tried:

```r
datanew <- data %>% 
  group_by(year, species, nest.code)%>% 
  mutate(Real_success = ifelse(success ==1 & 0, 0, success))
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output?

Comment: sorry, if it was not clear. If you press the hyperlink you will see the data structure. I would like to have one success outcome (single 0 or 1) per nest, NOT multiple. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you imagine it to look in the end. Do you want to have all rows preserved, do you want to have it ordered in some way. Anyway, this is what I came up with:

UPDATE: Sry, I missed "fledged" in the first answer

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(year, species, nest.code)%>%
  arrange(year, species, nest.code, success) %>%
  mutate(success = ifelse(row_number() > 1, NA, success))

# A tibble: 15 x 9
# Groups:   year, species, nest.code [5]
   date       nest.code  year species visit  eggs chicks outcome     success
   <fct>      <fct>     <int> <fct>   <int> <int>  <int> <fct>         <int>
 1 17/05/2018 D046       2018 AA          2     0     NA rearing           1
 2 5/05/2018  D046       2018 AA          1     1      0 incubating       NA
 3 14/06/2018 D046       2018 AA          3     0     NA unknown          NA
 4 14/06/2018 D047       2018 AA          3     0      0 nest failed       0
 5 21/05/2018 D047       2018 AA          2     0      1 rearing          NA
 6 6/05/2018  D047       2018 AA          1     1      0 incubating       NA
 7 14/06/2018 D062       2018 AA          3     0      0 nest failed       0
 8 17/05/2018 D062       2018 AA          2     0      2 rearing          NA
 9 6/05/2018  D062       2018 AA          1     2      0 incubating       NA
10 14/06/2018 D063       2018 AA          3     0      0 nest failed       0
11 21/05/2018 D063       2018 AA          2     0      1 rearing          NA
12 6/05/2018  D063       2018 AA          1     1      0 incubating       NA
13 14/06/2018 W18003     2018 BB          3     0      1 fledged           1
14 6/05/2018  W18003     2018 BB          1     1      0 incubating       NA
15 17/05/2018 W18003     2018 BB          2     0     NA unknown          NA
```

there definitly will be some easier way to do this. No pro in dplyr myself.
If it works, I'm happy.

Comment: thank you so much, i like the trick you used "arrange". it help me to move forward with my data, tnx again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that puts a zero in all rows for nests with at least one fail, a 1 if there is at least one success and no fail, and NA otherwise:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  group_by(year, species, nest.code) %>% 
  mutate(real_success = case_when(
    sum(1-success, na.rm = T) > 0   ~   0, # There was a fail
    sum(success,   na.rm = T) > 0   ~   1,
    TRUE                            ~   NA_real_)) %>%
 ungroup()

# A tibble: 15 x 10
   date       nest.code  year species visit  eggs chicks fate       success real_success
   <fct>      <fct>     <int> <fct>   <int> <int>  <int> <fct>        <int>        <dbl>
 1 5/05/2018  D046       2018 AA          1     1      0 incubating      NA            1
 2 17/05/2018 D046       2018 AA          2     0     NA rearing          1            1
 3 14/06/2018 D046       2018 AA          3     0     NA unknown         NA            1
 4 6/05/2018  D047       2018 AA          1     1      0 incubating      NA            0
 5 21/05/2018 D047       2018 AA          2     0      1 rearing          1            0
 6 14/06/2018 D047       2018 AA          3     0      0 nest fail…       0            0
 7 6/05/2018  D062       2018 AA          1     2      0 incubating      NA            0
 8 17/05/2018 D062       2018 AA          2     0      2 rearing          1            0
 9 14/06/2018 D062       2018 AA          3     0      0 nest fail…       0            0
10 6/05/2018  D063       2018 AA          1     1      0 incubating      NA            0
11 21/05/2018 D063       2018 AA          2     0      1 rearing          1            0
12 14/06/2018 D063       2018 AA          3     0      0 nest fail…       0            0
13 6/05/2018  W18003     2018 BB          1     1      0 incubating      NA            1
14 17/05/2018 W18003     2018 BB          2     0     NA unknown         NA            1
15 14/06/2018 W18003     2018 BB          3     0      1 fledged          1            1
```